# PDO-OCI driver on Zend Server

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to install PDO OCI driver on Zend server.. i had it installed on my os, modified the php.ini file in zend directory, and added e

```
extension=/path/to/pdo_oci.so
```

When I restart the apache, and try to access a php file, I am seeing ***Segmentation fault*** error

Could any one please help me correct the process of having the aforementioned driver on zend server.. As per zend config, pdo-oci driver is not shipped.. so was wondering on the alternate way of integrate with zend..

Appreciate the help..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the oci8 extension installed?

As far as I'm aware the PDO OCI driver is dependant on it.
There should be a extension=oci8.so present in either your php.ini or similar file, such as oci8.ini for example.

You also may need to set some environment variables in your virtualhost definition:

```
    SetEnv ORACLE_HOME /opt/oracle/instantclient
    SetEnv TNS_ADMIN   /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client/network/admin/network/admin
```

ORACLE_HOME should point to where you have installed the instantclient.